# Git hangs while trying to commit on OSX

Tags: macos, git

I am trying to run a commit by issuing the command:

```
 git commit -m "commit message"
```

The terminal window sometimes hangs, and I cannot figure out the source of the problem. The hanging disappears after I restart my computer, but eventually returns.

I am using OSX 10.6.8. I am not experiencing this problem with other commands (e.g. add, push)

What might be the source of this hanging and how can I go about resolving the problem?

Comment: I have this problem when working over a wireless network. It goes away when I connect with a wire.

Comment: How big is the repo? Is this the first commit? If you exit (`ctl-c`) do you get any error messages?

Comment: Thanks @redhotvengeance. The repo is pretty big and was able to commit after cleaning it up. (No error message with ctl-c)

Comment: @kl3755 Glad you got it solved.

Comment: For other idiots like me: make sure you don't forget the closing double quote...

Comment: For other idiots like me: make sure it's not just because your editor opened and is waiting for a commit message (I was doing an --amend)

Comment: Another gotcha that burned me: I have a pre-commit hook configured to trigger a CI build. If my CI server goes down, git hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Using -a is not a good idea as it will add ALL your files even though you are not adding them explicitly.

A question to ask is, does the repo has a lot files?

A suggestion is to add only the files you want. Then just do

```
git commit -m "Hello commit"
```

Comment: Same problem when I remove the -a flag. Problem was resolved when I reduced the repo size.